# Volume Shapes Calculator

Tags: c++, function

I was trying out c++ function and recursion but it seems I'm having quite a problem in the variable. I left a comment below where the error usually is found. I dont know where is my problem hoping someone can help me point it out. Thank you! Is it the Variables? or the whole program is flawed? ;-;

```cpp
#include <conio.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float Volume_Cube(float s);
float Volume_Sphere(float r);
float Volume_Rectangle(float w, float h, float l);

int main() {
  char opt;
  float V;
  do {
    do {
      cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
      cout << "         Mark Justine H. Monterde" << endl;
      cout << "         Volume of Shapes" << endl;
      cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
      cout << "            [C]-cube" << endl;
      cout << "            [S]-Sphere" << endl;
      cout << "            [R]-Rectangular Parallelepiped" << endl;
      cout << "            [X]-Exit" << endl;
      cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;

      cin >> opt;
      switch (opt) {
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
          float side;
          cout << "Enter side: " << endl;
          cin >> side;
          V = Volume_Cube(side);
          cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
          cout << "The Volume of the cube is " << V << endl;
          break;

        case 'S':
        case 's':
          float radius;
          cout << "Enter Radius: " << endl;
          cin >> radius;
          V = Volume_Sphere(radius);
          cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
          cout << "The Volume of the Sphere is " << V << endl;
          break;

        case 'R':
        case 'r':
          float width, height, length;
          cout << "Enter Length: " << endl;
          cin >> length;
          cout << "Enter Width: " << endl;
          cin >> width;
          cout << "Enter Height: " << endl;
          cin >> height;
          V = Volume_Rectangle(width, height, length);
          cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
          cout << "The Volume of the Rectangular Parallelepiped is " << V
               << endl;
          break;

        case 'X':
        case 'x':
          return 0;
          break;

        default:
          cout << "Denied...." << endl;
      }
      cout << "\nPress any key to continue...\n";
      _getch();
    } while (opt != 'X ' && opt != 'x');
    cout << "\nThank you for using the program \n";
    return 0;
  }

  float Volume_Cube(float s) {  //<-mostly my errors comes from here//

    float VOLUME;
    VOLUME = s * s * s;
    return VOLUME;
  }
  float Volume_Sphere(float r) {
    float VOLUME;
    const float PI = 3.14;
    VOLUME = ((4 / 3) * PI * r * r * r);
    return VOLUME;
  }
  float Volume_Rectangle(float w, float h, float l) {
    float VOLUME;
    VOLUME = w * h * l;
    return VOLUME;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot define a function within the body of another one.

Comment: Please show the eroor you get. P.S. I can not see any recursion in your code.

Comment: You are missing a `while(...)` after the first `do`. Also all your functions are defined _inside_ the function body of `main`, that is, you have misplaced `}`. Use your IDE's formatting feature tpo properly indent your code and spot such errors.

Comment: Apparently you define the `Volume_Cube` function and the other two _inside_ the `main` function, which is not allowed. Move them outside the closing brace of `main`.

Comment: This code is riddled with errors. After conio.h isn't found, _getchar() doesn't exist, then multi-character character constants, a do loop missing a while, etc. Outermost do (the one missing a while) isn't needed, and after getting fixing those errors, there's an extra closing brace at the end of the program. Finally, it compiles.

Comment: And the cube volume is correct. `Volume_Sphere()` will give a bad result due to `(4 / 3)` being integer division.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code again, with the compiler errors and warnings fixed. It now behaves as [mostly] expected. I placed comments where I made changes and marked them with the text `CHANGE:` . Your logic was sound, the syntax was just sloppy.

One area that I have not made changes to is how you exit. You immediately return, which means that your code below (thank you message, etc.) is never executed. Making those changes hinders this answer (in my opinion), so I'll leave it pointed out for you to work on. Suggestions are in the comments to this answer as of this writing.

```cpp
// #include <conio.h>  // CHANGE: Removed; outdated and not standard

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float Volume_Cube(float s);
float Volume_Sphere(float r);
float Volume_Rectangle(float w, float h, float l);

int main() {
  char opt;
  float V;
  // do {  // CHANGE: Removed
  do {
    cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "         Mark Justine H. Monterde" << endl;
    cout << "         Volume of Shapes" << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "            [C]-cube" << endl;
    cout << "            [S]-Sphere" << endl;
    cout << "            [R]-Rectangular Parallelepiped" << endl;
    cout << "            [X]-Exit" << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************************" << endl;

    cin >> opt;
    switch (opt) {
      case 'C':
      case 'c':
        float side;
        cout << "Enter side: " << endl;
        cin >> side;
        V = Volume_Cube(side);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
        cout << "The Volume of the cube is " << V << endl;
        break;

      case 'S':
      case 's':
        float radius;
        cout << "Enter Radius: " << endl;
        cin >> radius;
        V = Volume_Sphere(radius);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
        cout << "The Volume of the Sphere is " << V << endl;
        break;

      case 'R':
      case 'r':
        float width, height, length;
        cout << "Enter Length: " << endl;
        cin >> length;
        cout << "Enter Width: " << endl;
        cin >> width;
        cout << "Enter Height: " << endl;
        cin >> height;
        V = Volume_Rectangle(width, height, length);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
        cout << "The Volume of the Rectangular Parallelepiped is " << V << endl;
        break;

      case 'X':
      case 'x':
        return 0;
        break;

      default:
        cout << "Denied...." << endl;
    }
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...\n";
    // _getch();  // CHANGE: Removed; Not found
  } while (opt != 'X' && opt != 'x');  // CHANGE: Extra space after X removed
  cout << "\nThank you for using the program \n";
  return 0;
}

float Volume_Cube(float s) {  //<-mostly my errors comes from here//

  float VOLUME;
  VOLUME = s * s * s;
  return VOLUME;
}
float Volume_Sphere(float r) {
  float VOLUME;
  const float PI = 3.14;
  VOLUME = ((4.0 / 3.0) * PI * r * r * r);  // CHANGE: integers to doubles
  return VOLUME;
}
float Volume_Rectangle(float w, float h, float l) {
  float VOLUME;
  VOLUME = w * h * l;
  return VOLUME;
}
// }  // CHANGE: Removed
```

Proper formatting, and enabling compiler warnings caught all of these without the need for any actual investigations.

Proper styling can be achieved in many ways. In my case, my editor (VS Code) performs some styling automatically like auto-indents. But I also back that up with a tool, clang-format.

For warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` should be considered a minimum. Some people might recommend a couple others to go with these, but I consider this a good minimum.

Comment: Yet another omission to fix: the message `"Thank you for using the program"` will never show due to `return` under `case 'x':`. It can be improved with an additional boolean flag `exiting` set under the case label instead of returning, and then used to terminate a `do` loop.

Comment: Good points, I didn't catch those. My intention was to make the minimal changes needed to ensure the volume functions were working; and the program [mostly] works fine after fixing the compilation errors and warnings. I think your comment is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are declearing functions inside main, that is a function itself, and this is illegal, try declearing them outside.

Comment: "_You are declearing functions inside main_" No, OP is not. OP is defining functions inside a `main`. Only declaring them, would be fine.